# Does the openssh server have a metrics endpoint that can be queried via prometheus?

Tags: openssh

Does the openssh server have a metrics endpoint that can be queried via prometheus?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything by searching the internet. Perhaps there is also a service monitor that could be put to good use here.